# Terminate Spring Cloud Task on OutOfMemory exception

Tags: out-of-memory, spring-cloud-stream, cloud-foundry

I have a Spring task app deployed on PCF. This app get OutOfMemory exception but not terminate the task. 
Many people suggested setting env -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p" solve this problem. How can I set it on PCF?

Answer (score 0):

When you run an app on Cloud Foundry, the Java buildpack will run and emit a start command which includes a Java agent that properly handles this for you. It's called the `jvmkill` agent.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/jvmkill#overview

This will monitor your app for OOME's and if one happens, print some debug info and kill the app. I believe this is exactly the behavior that you're discussing above, but unlike the way you mentioned this method will print debug info prior to killing the app and IMHO is generally more reliable.

For tasks running on Cloud Foundry, the Java buildpack still installs the kill agent, but it cannot actually insert the kill agent into the start command for your task. This is because CF tasks take the start command entirely from the user.

The general recommendation for starting Java based tasks on CF, is to take the start command generated by the Java buildpack to run your app or another app with the same memory limit and adjust it to start your task instead.

For example, here is the start command generated for Spring Music:

`JAVA_OPTS="-agentpath:$PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/jvmkill-1.16.0_RELEASE=printHeapHistogram=1 -Djava.io.tmpdir=$TMPDIR -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=$(nproc) -Djava.ext.dirs= -Djava.security.properties=$PWD/.java-buildpack/java_security/java.security $JAVA_OPTS" && CALCULATED_MEMORY=$($PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java-buildpack-memory-calculator-3.13.0_RELEASE -totMemory=$MEMORY_LIMIT -loadedClasses=27062 -poolType=metaspace -stackThreads=250 -vmOptions="$JAVA_OPTS") && echo JVM Memory Configuration: $CALCULATED_MEMORY && JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $CALCULATED_MEMORY" && MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2 SERVER_PORT=$PORT eval exec $PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $PWD/.:$PWD/.java-buildpack/container_security_provider/container_security_provider-1.16.0_RELEASE.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher`

Note the `-agentpath:$PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/jvmkill-1.16.0_RELEASE=printHeapHistogram=1` part, which starts the jvmkill agent.

Now if I want to adjust this to run `java -version`. I could do the following:

`JAVA_OPTS="-agentpath:$PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/jvmkill-1.16.0_RELEASE=printHeapHistogram=1 -Djava.io.tmpdir=$TMPDIR -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=$(nproc) -Djava.ext.dirs= -Djava.security.properties=$PWD/.java-buildpack/java_security/java.security $JAVA_OPTS" && CALCULATED_MEMORY=$($PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java-buildpack-memory-calculator-3.13.0_RELEASE -totMemory=$MEMORY_LIMIT -loadedClasses=27062 -poolType=metaspace -stackThreads=250 -vmOptions="$JAVA_OPTS") && echo JVM Memory Configuration: $CALCULATED_MEMORY && JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $CALCULATED_MEMORY" && MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2 SERVER_PORT=$PORT eval exec $PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -version`

Note how I just changed the end, where the actual Java arguments are set.

The commands are quite long, but they do end up working and should do the trick for you.

Comment: A quick tip: if you want to make *nix commands more readable in your own code, you can use the line continuation character (backslash \\) at the end, and then continue the command on the next line. Unfortunately this can't be used inside your long env vars here, but it can be used at the `&&` points.